# What emacs communities exist?

Tags: learning

Please maintain a community wiki answer which describes email lists, wikis, blogs, irc channels, forums, or other communities in which GNU Emacs is the primary topic.

In order to be listed, a community must be 'open', meaning that anyone can participate.

Exceptions to that rule can, should, and have been made.  Employ judgement.  For example: of course Sacha's blog and Xah's site belong on this list.

Comment: Idea: merge all the answers in one and make this answer Community Wiki. So it won't be too broad.

Comment: Agree with @nicael on the community wiki option: I'd like to see such a list, but it doesn't lend itself well to the Q&A format on this site.

Comment: Personal blogs are not generally available to communities to participate in, other than by adding comments. If this page is kept (too broad IMO), I think it should at least be limited to general, open Emacs communities.

Comment: The community wiki answer below is exactly what I was looking for!  Is it possible for me to withdraw the question without losing the answer?  Or, how should the question be edited so that it is an appropriate container for the answer?

Comment: Have mercy on me, I've completely changed this original question.  Please review the edit history.  Please edit the question.  Heck, make the question CW, too.  I'd love to abandon the question so long as the answer will remain and be maintained over time.  BTW, please advise me how to stop receiving down votes for this question... :P

Comment: @daveloyall I've flagged this so that a moderator can make it CW. *(FWIW, 2 downvotes is not that much for this type of question)*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Emacs communities and forums, in addition to this site

- [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/)
- [WikiEmacs](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- GNU Emacs [mailing lists](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/) (search for "emacs" in the list)

  - [help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/) archive (also available via news:gnu.emacs.help and [google groups](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gnu.emacs.help))
  - [emacs-devel@gnu.org](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/) archive
  - [help-emacs-windows@gnu.org](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-emacs-windows/) archive
- [Stack Overflow with `emacs` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emacs?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

  - Similarly, filter these for [emacs](/questions/tagged/emacs) or [elisp](/questions/tagged/elisp): [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [TeX – LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)
  - Or use [this filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/148229/emacs) across all of StackExchange.
- [Emacs on Quora](http://www.quora.com/Emacs)
- [Emacs on Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/communities/114815898697665598016)
- [Emacs on Live Journal](http://emacs.livejournal.com)
- [Reddit's /r/emacs](http://reddit.com/r/emacs)
- [Emacs on http://community.linuxmint.com](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/emacs)
- IRC: #emacs on freenode
- IRC: #org-mode on freenode

#### Blogs

- [Planet Emacsen (blog aggreggator)](http://planet.emacsen.org/)
- [Endless Parentheses](http://endlessparentheses.com) (it is [Malabarba's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/50/malabarba))
- [Emacs Redux](http://emacsredux.com)
- [Mastering Emacs](http://www.masteringemacs.org/)
- [Null program](http://nullprogram.com/tags/emacs/)
- [Irreal](http://irreal.org/blog/?tag=emacs)
- [Emacs Rocks!](http://emacsrocks.com/)
- [Lunarsite](http://www.lunaryorn.com/index.html)
- [The Kitchin Research Group](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/category/emacs/)
- [Sacha Chua](http://sachachua.com/blog/category/emacs/)
- [Yoo Box](https://yoo2080.wordpress.com/category/emacs/)
- [Ergoemacs](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/blog.html)
- [Emacs Mini Manual](http://tuhdo.github.io/)

Comment: This is community wiki post; feel free to edit and add more communities.

Comment: FWIW: I don't really see anything (useful) at the Facebook Emacs page.

Comment: Shameless plug: http://mbork.pl/CategoryEmacs .

Answer (score 1):

[emacs.zeef.com](http://emacs.zeef.com) is actually an impressive resource for anything that's Emacs related, communities included.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is "vim" converter (like me), then there is also `spacemacs` quite active community: [Spacemacs github](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs)

We have gitter chatroom (and IRC room connected with it): [Gitter](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more to be added at your convenience.

http://emacsmovies.org/

https://github.com/emacs-tw/awesome-emacs

http://emacs.sexy/

https://tuhdo.github.io/emacs-tutor.html

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Emacs_Lisp